# Crystal reports organising data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, formatting

I am using Crystal Reports 13_0_2 in C# Visual Studio 2010. Everything is working but I need some advice to format data from my database. I am new in programming and especially in crystal reports. In my project I am using crystal report viewer tool to shoot the report.

Let's say that the following is the data I'm using:

```
Col1     Col2 
value1   abc 
value2   abc
value3   def
value4   def
value5   abc
value6   abc
value7   def
value8   def
```

I need to make multiple report from the database, like this 
First report:

```
Col1     Col2 
value1   abc 
value2   abc
value5   abc
value6   abc
```

Second report:

```
Col1     Col2 
value3   def
value4   def
value7   def
value8   def
```

and so on.

So I need to group data by second col and show abc and def names in group tree on the left side. It is probably easy but I have no clue how to do it. So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "Col2" to be what you group on just choose to "insert group" and choose the column you want to group on.

Another option would be to make the first column on the main report and "insert subeport" where you can show "child data" under each "parent data" row.

Comment: +1 for grouping - OP will probably want to suppress group header and footer, and to add a page break on change of group.